# Why exception can't stop Action?

Tags: c#, exception

Below is my code:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomHandler());
    }
}
public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do something before
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        // do something after
    }
}
public class BaseActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        throw new Exception("Test exception");
    }
}
[RoutePrefix("api")]
[BaseActionFilter]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("t1")]
    public string TestMethod()
    {
        // this code still executed
        return "api: " + DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

when I comment CustomHandler, the code run well, and [TestMethod] will not running.
but when I added CustomHandler, the Exception can't stop runing [TestMethod].

How did I do, so can stop runing [TestMethod]?
I don't want use :
`actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage();`
because many exception type will throw.
thanks.

Comment: Try making `OnActionExecuting` non async

Comment: https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/06/19/exception-handling-in-asynchronous-code/

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks, but I need actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), it must be async.

Comment: @MatthewLayton but why I delete CustomHandler, it's works well.